# Not able to insert class object inside set in C++?

Tags: c++, set

The compiler is showing error saying
23:18: error: passing 'const A' as 'this' argument of 'void A::show()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
Wondering where I am using const in this program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    int i;
    public:
    A(int pi):i(pi) {}
    void show() { cout<<i<<endl; }
    ~A() { cout<<"Destructor : "<<i<<endl; }
};
int main()
{
   set <A> s;

   s.emplace(A(40));
   s.emplace(A(10));
   s.emplace(A(30));
   s.emplace(A(20));
   set <A>::iterator it;
   for(it = s.begin(); it != s.end() ; it++)      // Line 23
      (*it).show();
   return 0;
}
```

I got the answer of above code , but Why in case of pointer it is working fine . e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    int i;
    public:
    A(int pi):i(pi) {}
    void show() { cout<<i<<endl; }
    ~A() { cout<<"Destructor : "<<i<<endl; }
};
int main()
{
   set <A *> s;
   s.emplace(new A(40));
   s.emplace(new A(10));
   s.emplace(new A(30));
   s.emplace(new A(20));
   set <A *>::iterator it;
   for(it = s.begin(); it != s.end() ; it++)
      (*it)->show();
   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT: 
40
10
30
20
I know in this case I need to define my own deleter as well . Just thinking about how to do that ?

Comment: Where you're using `const` in this program: [**look here**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin). Since `show` is not `const` thus your error. Since C++11 `std::set::iterator` is `const` bi-directional. Make `show` to be `const` and it should work.

Comment: Honestly, I'm more impressed with how you're managing to store a class type `A` in a set with no means of comparator. Sooner or later you're gonna have to take care of that too.

Comment: Well I checked the both kinds of iterators const and non const are there . But yes after making function show const and yes Comparator function it is working fine  . But if I insert pointer object of the same class type it is working fine and showing no error and neither requires comparator function either , but yes not storing pointer object on the basis of int element i , but just in the order the elements are inserted . Could you please clarify why it is so .

Comment: It works with pointers, because here the pointer is const, show() does not modify the pointer.

Comment: Please read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). And consider accepting the answers that have helped you.

Answer (score 1):

A set contains a **sorted** set of unique objects. To sort the object, a comparator is required, something like this:

```
bool operator<(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) {
    return lhs.i < rhs.i; // assuming 'i' is public
}
```

I can't see any comparator in you code, are you sure you are able to insert class 'A' objects into the set?

To fix the "line 23"-error, just mark the method `show()` as `const`, since the iterator in `const`:

```
void show() const { cout << i << endl; }
```

Another workaround would be `const_cast`, but it's bad practice:

```
const_cast<A&>(*it).show();
```

---

Note that `const` makes very well sense in this context. Otherwise you could potentially change an object that is already sorted (eg: change the value `i`). And that could break the sort order.

Comment: Well I added one  struct A_comp 
{
    bool operator() (const A & lhs, const A & rhs) const
    {
              return lhs.intake() < rhs.intake();
    }
};int intake() const { return i; }

Comment: Well const_cast<A&>(*it).show();  that is a master stroke I guess . Its working .

Comment: Ew... that's literally the worst thing you can do, @user379. Fix your function instead.